# updating interfaces which are validated by wcf validation block

Tags: c#, wcf, validation

I have an Interface and in some month I want to add parameters to that interface.

I read somewhere (link went missing) that when I use Datacontracts I can easily add Properties to the datacontract. The new Properties will just not be sent to the server on old clients.

In Theory I just have one Interface and my new and old client can use that Interface. Did I understand that correct?

But Now I am working with the [validation Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc467894.aspx) from Microsoft. Does that break my "feature" of having interfaces which are easy to maintain?

What is a good way of managing different version of interfaces with the validation block?

Comment: Do you mean new Properties?

Comment: yes. Because when I use Objects with DataContracts I mostly set Properties there.

Comment: that was a prompt for you to edit your question to be more precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't really clear on whether you mean changes to methods on `ServiceContracts`, or changes to data in `DataContracts`, however, there is a degree of non-breaking change compatability in both:

For [Service Contracts, From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731060%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Adding service operations exposed by the service is a nonbreaking change because existing clients need not be concerned about those new operations.

With the proviso:

> Adding operations to a duplex callback contract is a breaking change.

Adding new parameters at the end existing method signatures may work for client calls from old versions, but would result in a default value for the type being passed - e.g. null for reference types, zero for numeric types, etc. This might break things and require additional validation (e.g. `DateTime.MinValue` wouldn't gel well with a Sql `DateTime` column.

Similarly, for `DataContracts`, [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731138%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> In most cases, adding or removing a data member is not a breaking change, unless you require strict schema validity (new instances validating against the old schema).

New datamember properties would be defaulted, and obsolete / removed properties would be ignored.

You can also rename members using the `Name` property on `DataMembers`.

VAB would be subject to the same rules - i.e. any validations on new fields would need to be aware of the defaults provided, which would imply you couldn't validate new fields.

Doing changes like this retroactively is not a good idea once you have clients connecting to your services - it pays to design an interface right first time, and then to have a versioning strategy going forward, where you can provide a facade for older clients to connect to an old interface, which then actually transforms the old format to the new one, and makes deliberate mapping and defaulting decisions about missing or obsolete data.

Comment: The is also the OnDeserialization attribute which you can use to add some mapping code.